# Will moving iron golems allow more to spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I have one village that spawns iron golems, could I simply move the iron golem 100+ blocks away from the village to allow more to spawn? Or will the golem have to be killed to allow more to spawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called **Iron Golem Farming** and it's a widely used method of obtaining an infinite source of iron golems or iron ingots.

Quoting the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming):

> An Iron Golem farm is an easy way to acquire many iron ingots (and
> less useful poppies) with minimal effort after the initial setup. It
> is an artificial village (or several of them, spaced far enough apart
> to remain separate) in which golems are spawned and then either killed
> immediately, or moved to a holding cell **(outside the village boundary,
> so that new ones can spawn in their place)** for later killing.

Answer (score -2):

you will have to kill or move the iron golem.